# Classes & functions calling invoking object

Tags: c++, objective-c, class

I have two questions about my program. The program i made creates 2 fraction objects and does arithmetic with them. 
First, is it possible for a function in the class.cpp file to have multiple objects as its parameter:

```
int Rational::addNums(Rational f1, Rational f2)
```

Secondly, in my code, for some reason my program never reach the addNums function call when executed. It seems to stop after the getDenom() function. Im not sure why this would be happening.

```
class Rational
{
public:
    Rational(int = 2, int = 4);//default constructor thats set numerator and denominator with default values

    //set functions
    void setFrac(int, int);
    void setNumer(int);
    void setDenom(int);

    //get functions
    int getNumer() const;
    int getDenom() const;

    //arithmetic functions
    int addNums(Rational, Rational);
    int subNums(int, int);
    int multNums(int, int);
    int divNums(int, int);


    void DisplayFracs(int);
    void DisplayDecimals(float);


private:
    int num;//numerator of fraction1
    int den;//denominator of fraction1

};

#include <iostream>
#include "Rational.h"

using namespace std;


Rational::Rational(int num, int den)
{
    setFrac(num, den);
}

void Rational::setFrac( int n, int d)
{
    setNumer(n);
    setDenom(d);
}

void Rational::setNumer(int n)
{
    if ( n != 0)
        num = n;
    else
        cout << n << " is not a valid number." << endl;

    }

void Rational::setDenom(int d)
{
    if ( d != 0)
        den = d;
    else
        cout << d << " is not a valid number." << endl;
}

int Rational::getNumer()const
{
    return num;
}

int Rational::getDenom() const
{
    return den;
}

int Rational::addNums(Rational f1, Rational f2)
{
    int m = f1.den;
    int n = f2.den;

        int temp = 0;
        if(m < n)
        {
            temp = m;
            m = n;
            n = temp;
        }
    cout << m << "  :   " << n << endl;
        while(n != 0)
        {
            temp = m % n;
            m = n;
            n = temp;
        }
    cout << m << "  :   " << n << endl;
        return f1.den = m;
        return f2.den = n;

}

int main()
{
    Rational f1(2,7);
    Rational f2(3,8);

    cout << f1.getDenom()<< "   :   " << f2.getDenom() << endl;
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Where do you call `addNums` in this sample code?

Comment: I don't follow the first question - are you just asking whether a function can have more than one parameter? Of course it can (although you want `addNums` to return a `Rational`, with a single `return` statement). As for the second question: your `main` never calls `addNums`, so of course the program never reaches that function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can pass any number of built-in/user-defined objects as long as your cpp file knows what these objects stand for. In case of plain objects cpp file should know the definition of these objects but for pointers declaration is sufficient.
Regarding second question:- I can't see call to addnums anywhere.